# Optimization of query/calling function

Tags: php, optimization, foreach, query-optimization

I am getting users from database and returning them as array. Query returns 22000 users, which are correct, now i am trying to save these users info CSV file, but before this i have to check extra features of each user e.g **Applied Opportunities**, so checking each single user , getting each single **ID** from array and passing it to the other function takes lot and lot of time, and i have 9 other functions that i need to check on. What is the best and optimized way to do this. Please see the code below

```
$sql = "SELECT id, first_name,last_name,position_id,user_company,role,last_login_date,
sf_id,user_email,login_count,user_registered FROM er_users";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$query = $query->result_array();

foreach ($query as $key => $q) {
   $a_opps = vt_applied_opps((object)$q);
   $s_opps = vt_suggested_opps((object)$q);
   $i_requests_e = vt_interview_request((object)$q);
   $i_requests_c = vt_company_interview_request((object)$q);

   $i_to_apply = get_invitations_count($q["id"]);
   $councils = vt_ac_count((object)$q);
   $cbe = vt_cbe_credits((object)$q);
   $forum = vt_forums((object)$q);
   $bio = vt_is_bio((object)$q);
   $resume = vt_is_resume((object)$q);

   $q["a_opps"] = $a_opps;
   $q["s_opps"] = $s_opps;
   $q["i_requests_e"] = $i_requests_e;
   $q["i_requests_c"] = $i_requests_c;

   $q["i_to_apply"] = $i_to_apply;
   $q["councils"] = $councils;
   $q["cbe"] = $cbe;
   $q["forum"] = $forum;
   $q["bio"] = $bio;
   $q["resume"] = $resume;
   $query[$key] = $q;
}
```

These are the functions, and their results is being stored in variable and then those variables are being used in an array. Please help me to optimize this method. As there are 22K records, so foreach loop is running 22K times and inner functions are 22K times as well, please help me to optimize this way.

Comment: Do the functions inside the foreach contain queries?

Comment: The best way - get all additional data with one sql query. For example instead calling vt_applied_opps((object)$q) for each user, make single sql query that return data for all users.

Comment: Can these functions be moved to the database? Perhaps a stored procedure.

Comment: Is the information from these other functions stored within the database? If so then why not use subqueries to gather all of the information in a single pass? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

> $sql = "SELECT id,
>   first_name,last_name,position_id,user_company,role,last_login_date,
>   sf_id,user_email,login_count,user_registered FROM er_users";
>   If you only need id then remove remaining table field from SELECT clause.

Second,

> $a_opps = vt_applied_opps((object)$q);    $s_opps =
>   vt_suggested_opps((object)$q);    $i_requests_e =
>   vt_interview_request((object)$q);    $i_requests_c =
>   vt_company_interview_request((object)$q);
>
> $i_to_apply = get_invitations_count($q["id"]);    $councils =
>   vt_ac_count((object)$q);    $cbe = vt_cbe_credits((object)$q);
>   $forum = vt_forums((object)$q);    $bio = vt_is_bio((object)$q);
>   $resume = vt_is_resume((object)$q);

If these all function getting the appropriate results from the database only , then you can JOIN those tables with the above SQL, and ignore the function call.

These really might help.

Also check the Table.field indexing, if you are using the fields in WHERE clause, and those fields does not have indexing, then please add indexing for those fields make fast SELECT SQL.

Comment: i cannot use joins as because the records in database are above 100K so they will become more slow ....

Comment: JOIN will become slow, but if you will use indexing, it will become fast.